# Which is faster for Azure table query: a single query on an arbitrary column, or many queries with the row/partition keys?

Tags: azure

I have a bunch of data (we'll say a few million rows), and want to query it on a key that is *not* the RowKey or PartitionKey. So to facilitate this, I created an index table, where the PartitionKey is a static string value, and the RowKey is the value of the key I want to query on. To illustrate:

```
**CHARACTERS**
PartitionKey  RowKey  DateKilled  FavoriteFood
----------------------------------------------
Stark         Arya    299 AL      Hot Cakes
Stark         Bran    301 AL      Pigeon Pie
Stark         Rickon  ---         Berries
Lannister     Cersie  300 AL      Boar
Lannister     Tywin   299 AL      Beating hearts of innocents
Lannister     Tyrion  ---         Wine

**CHARACTERSIDX**
PartitionKey    RowKey  Chars
----------------------------------
date_killed_idx 299 AL    [{House: Stark, Name: Arya}, {House: Lannister, Name:Tywin}]
date_killed_idx 300 AL    [{House: Lannister, Name:Cersie}]
date_killed_idx 301 AL    [{House: Stark, Name: Bran}]
```

Given the above data, I want to find the favorite food of everyone killed in 299 AL. The two ways to do this:

1) Query **CHARACTERS** and filter by DateKilled (which would require a full table scan)

2) Query **CHARACTERSIDX**, and then for each entry in `299 AL`, query the individual rows from **CHARACTERS**, one at a time.

So for this contrived example, it doesn't matter. But imagine if the number of rows in **CHARACTERS** is 1, 10, or 100 million, and the number of Houses and characters is also in the same range (not many grouped together by partition). Would it be better to do a single poorly optimized query? Or 10,000, 50,000, etc single queries using the output of a single optimized query from **CHARACTERSIDX**?  Or am I approaching this entirely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far, your second option.  You always want to do point queries (a query specifying both partition key and rowkey).  Your first option (querying over lots of entities for a non-indexed field) will result in throttling and poor performance and is only appropriate for very infrequent or unplanned queries.  If you haven't read it yet, I would highly recommend:

[Azure Storage Table Design Guide](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/)

Comment: Fair enough - will give that a look over. Is there any support for 'union' to limit the number of connections I have to make, since each request is a web request to the storage API?